# How Galois connections between powersets correspond to binary relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, relations, galois-connections

How to show the well-known bijective correspondence between Galois connections (or rather polarities) between two powersets on some (fixed) sets with binary relations between these sets?

You can also point me some open access article.

Comment: I've found this at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Galois+connection#properties